# Why use Haskeline's outputStrLn vs. conventional putStrLn?

Tags: haskell, terminal, haskeline

My question: Is there any advantage to using Haskeline's `outputStrLn` over `putStrLn` for writing to the screen in a terminal program?

Background:

I recently introduced Haskeline into my terminal app in order to leverage the line-editing UI of the `getInputLine` function. (This required some significant changes to my monad transformer stack.)

I've since noticed that Haskeline comes with `outputStr` and `outputStrLn` functions for output. Now that I've gone to the trouble of adopting the library, I'm wondering if I should also prefer these output functions as opposed to the standard `putStr` and `putStrLn`. This would require more refactoring given the different monads returned by the functions in question.

Comment: I had a very quick look at the source and went a bit though the rabbit hole: it looks like it eventually calls `withCodingMode` to ensure the handle is in the right encoding and binary mode. The docs of `outputStr` say "Write a Unicode string to the user's standard output", which seems to confirm that suspicion. I'm not completely sure that's it, though.

Comment: I don’t know about the internals of Haskeline, but I once had an issue where if I used `liftIO` with either `putStrLn` or its equivalent in terms of `getExternalPrint`, then output would not appear immediately, yet `outputStr` worked correctly. So I assumed it must be expecting a certain buffering mode, or commandeering the terminal to render the prompt/editor, and that I must use `outputStr`, but I didn’t investigate further. Maybe this is a question for the Haskeline issue tracker?